# Objects aren't visible when I render the image

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I asked this question earlier without too much context. I attached the file of my blender project to provide better info. Here is what I wrote in in my previous thread:
So when I render the lamp most of the meshes don't show up. All objects are set to be rendered so I don't know why this is happening. Also when I copy the lamp and paste it in a new blender window, the same objects that won't show up when rendered in the original file won't show up in object or edit mode. 
I attached the file on the following link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9YfCDmAT5BNGVGOU1aRnRKclU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Instead of asking the same thing again in a different post, please edit the original one with the new information.

Comment: I deleted the original post.

Comment: @Midnightkimchiramen For future reference, it's preferred to provide clarifications and additional information by editing the original post.

Comment: could you add a screenshot of your rendered image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**LAYERS**

[image]

- Do the following for every object from largest object to the smallest.  In the object panel / Relations click on layer (1) so it is dark as in the image above, the upper left layer rectangle of 20 possible.  Then click render.
- These layers are coordinated with these Render Layer Settings

[image]

When a new simple file is created objects are on layer 1 and the render layer settings are showing at least layer 1.  Blender gives the user the flexibility to hide or show these layers at different times and phases.  It can be used as a feature or to create confusion.

If you want to know more you can now search at this website and blender.org and video site for information about [layers].  Quick Summary.  Every file can have multiple render layers.  Every render layer can select some of the twenty layers.  Every object can be on some render layers.  All 3 concepts must be coordinated with other hidden delights for an object to appear in the render.

Answer (score -2):

I don't have an answer; I would comment if I could, but I'm a n00b here and I don't have reputation points. But I wanted to throw in what I found.

I was playing around with joining and separating everything in the scene, and this monster appeared. I'm getting it to appear by selecting everything in the scene and joining. You might have to join/separate on repeat.

[image]

It breaks down into these parts, many of which seem redundant:
[image]

Have you seen this thing before? In edit mode, nothing shows as selected, though it behaves as if it is when I manipulate it. And once it appears, the verts count goes to 0.

I also noticed that the spring pieces disappear when they're joined.

If it's any solace, I'm thoroughly confused.

Comment: I am confused as to what you have done in the images. And I tried joining/separating although maybe my approach towards the process didn't change anything; I joined and separated each object by twos and I'm sure thats not the way to do it. Also, when in edit mode, individual objects do show as selected so I know as much as you do in this confusion. I did also notice that the springs disappeared when I joined them with their adjacent objects. I might as well try remodeling again.